# Python list comprehension of dynamic size

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have a list comprehension

```
[x,y,z] for x in a for y in a for z in a
```

Suppose this is the comprehension i get for size 3
I want to be able to modify it accordingly so for 2 i will only have x,y for 4 i'll have like a,b,c,d etc...

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: There probably is already a solution, but you're going to have to clarify the question a bit further first.

Comment: `[x,y,z] for x in a for y in a for z in a` is not valid Python syntax. Do you mean `[[x,y,z] for x in a for y in a for z in a]`? If not, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I think you meant :`for x in a for y in b for z in c`?

Comment: yup i meant [[x,y,z] for x in a for y in b for z in c]]
i want to have the same structure but for any number of variables x y z

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can use the [`product`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) function:

```
from itertools import product
a = [1,2,3]
print list(product(a))
# gives: [(1,), (2,), (3,)]
print list(product(a, a))
# gives: [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
print list(product(a, a, a))
# gives: [(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 1), (1, 3, 2), (1, 3, 3), (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 3), (2, 3, 1), (2, 3, 2), (2, 3, 3), (3, 1, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 1, 3), (3, 2, 1), (3, 2, 2), (3, 2, 3), (3, 3, 1), (3, 3, 2), (3, 3, 3)]
```

or more conveniently with the `repeat` keyword:

```
product(a, repeat=3)
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning the `repeat` keyword argument.

Comment: @DSM: Good point. That means the above can also be done with: `product(a, repeat=3)`.

Comment: Sorry i wasn't clear this is not exactly what i want.
for each element x y z etc... i am choosing one of two elements. I can't choose both, i'm just trying to get all the combinations where for each element i choose one or the other. not the entire cross product